# Filter for author list in gutenberg core editor

Tags: filters, post-meta, block-editor

Is there a filter to modify the presentation of certain editor editor components?  For my example, I want to be able to filter the author list which is a select input in the Gutenberg editor on the document pane.

I know the component I want to modify is located here:
https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/blob/8517779feddf3de0b86465fae8f21f4384447c58/packages/editor/src/components/post-author/index.js

Comment: Which functionality you want to add?

Comment: I want to be able to show more properties from the user object than just the pretty name.  We have a case where we have multiple username slugs with the same pretty name, and so we need to show both in the select box

Answer (score 1):

The component `post-author` uses `getAuthors()` to get the authors, this functions calls the REST API.

```js
export function* getAuthors() {
    const users = yield apiFetch( { path: '/wp/v2/users/?who=authors&per_page=-1' } );
    yield receiveUserQuery( 'authors', users );
}
```

So you can only filter via the REST API filter [rest_user_query](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/rest_user_query/), but this can have effects on other plugins which also use this endpoint to get the user list.

Comment: This is good to get the author list, so thank you for that.  But I need to then change the author based on this new list.  I'm trying to find a hook for that- is there a hook that would allow me to set the author?

Comment: How to get a current logged-in user?